# Typescript type inference from type parameters

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I don't understand why Typescript can't properly infer the types in the following case that involves inference from type parameters. (This question is similar to [TypeScript type inference issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531390/typescript-type-inference-issue) but is a somewhat different case. The answer may be the same, though, that I'm just out of luck!)

```
// A base class for a dialog taking parameter of type P
// and returning result of type R.
class BaseDialog<P, R> { p: P; r: R; }

class ValueDialog extends BaseDialog<string, number> {}

// A function that shows the dialog
show<T extends BaseDialog<P, R>, P, R>(dlg: Type<T>, param: P): Promise<R> {}
```

Note: To simplify the method signature, I'm using Angular's `Type`:

```
export interface Type<T> extends Function {
  new (...args: any[]): T;
}
```

Now, when I call the method `show`, as follows, the `R` type is not correctly inferred:

```
show(ValueDialog, "name").then(r => console.log(r));
```

The compiler infers:

```
T = ValueDialog
P = string
R = {}
```

Since `T` is correctly inferred, you'd think the compiler could infer `P` and `R` from `ValueDialog`'s definition, but it doesn't.

I can fix this, of course, by manually specifying the types, but that's pretty ugly. I can also fix it by making `P` and `R` the same, but that isn't the functionality I want.

How can I define `show()` so that it correctly infers `R`?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53448100/generic-type-of-extended-interface-not-inferred/53448204#53448204

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ca use a conditional type to extract type `R` parameter from the base type. You will need to use the `R` type in some way for this to work :

```
export interface Type<T> extends Function {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}
class BaseDialog<P, R> {
    value: R //we need to use R in some  way for the parameter to make a difference
}

class ValueDialog extends BaseDialog<string, number> {}


type ExtractResult<T extends BaseDialog<any, any>> = T extends BaseDialog<any, infer R> ? R : never; 
// A function that shows the dialog
declare function show<T extends BaseDialog<P, any>, P>(dlg: Type<T>, param: P): Promise<ExtractResult<T>>;

show(ValueDialog, "name").then(r => console.log(r)); // r is now string
```

Comment: This works! I can (mostly) follow the ExtractResult type, but I could never have come up with this on my own! I'm from the other link that this is the only way to infer types from a type parameter. Thank you for the help!